# optimisation procedures before training SVM

Tags: svm, optimization

I'm using the LIBSVM in Java for classification with 200 documents in inputs. I build/train the SVM using the same input training data.

My response time for preprocessing of documents (tokenization, filtering and ngrams and then writing results out to files) and loading file into memory  is 8 second.

Could anyone recommend a good methods (maybe tools) for preprocessing and loading my result into memory ??

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Why not storing your processed training data in a database?

Comment: your idea could be efficace. Can you explique more please ?